# Set up a special activity PendingIntent

Tags: android, notifications

I want open special activity when the app is closed and user tap on notification. But the special didnt open. When user will click to notification i want open `TestActivity` but instead of this  `MainActivity` opening all time.

In the manifest i have this code:

```
 <service
            android:name=".services.firebase.notification.AppFirebaseMessaging"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
.
.
.
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
.
.
.
 <activity android:name=".TestActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"/>
```

this is my AppFirebaseMessaging

```
class AppFirebaseMessaging : FirebaseMessagingService() {

 override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
// here parsing RemoteMessage object, 
sendNotification("title", "description")
}

private fun sendNotification(title: String, description: String) {
val random = System.currentTimeMillis().toInt()
        val notificationBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder = notificationBuilder(title, description)

        val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as? NotificationManager

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            notificationManager?.createNotificationChannel(getChannel(title))
        }

        notificationManager?.notify(random, notificationBuilder.build())

}

private fun notificationBuilder(title: String, description: String): NotificationCompat.Builder {
        val random = System.currentTimeMillis().toInt()
        val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)

        val notifyIntent = Intent(this, TestActivity::class.java).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        }
        val notifyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, notifyIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )
        val notificationBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, random.toString())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notification)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(description)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .apply {
                setContentIntent(notifyPendingIntent)
            }

        return notificationBuilder
    }
}
```

When user will click to notification, MainActivity will be open, dont understand why

Answer (score 0):

Tapping on Notification will always open the activity that has the following intent filter attributes.

```
   <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

If you can't make the 'TestActivity' the Main activity, you could try as follows.

Keep the MainActivity as the Main.
There set the launch mode to singleTop in MainActivity.

```
        <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
```

Then Override the 'onNewIntent' inside MainActivity,

```
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(@NonNull Intent intent) {
     super.onNewIntent(intent);
  
    // here send intent to open TestActivity

    }
```